# Error in exception.h : Visual C++ and mysql connection

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to connect `MySQL` database with `Visual C++.`
I'd download necessary files from MySQL's site it self. Then i followed instructions provided by site and i create my project.

Now when i hit Build then it gave me errors.

```
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : 'string'    c:\program files\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.7\include\cppconn\exception.h    98  1   MySQL_Connection
Error   2   error C2091: function returns function  c:\program files\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.7\include\cppconn\exception.h    98  1   MySQL_Connection
Error   3   error C2802: static member 'operator new' has no formal parameters  c:\program files\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.7\include\cppconn\exception.h    98  1   MySQL_Connection
Error   4   error C2333: 'sql::SQLException::operator new' : error in function declaration; skipping function body  c:\program files\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.7\include\cppconn\exception.h    98  1   MySQL_Connection
Error   5   error C2556: 'void *(__cdecl *sql::SQLException::operator new(void))(size_t,void *) throw()' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'void *(__cdecl *sql::SQLException::operator new(void))(size_t) throw(std::bad_alloc)'  c:\program files\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.7\include\cppconn\exception.h    98  1   MySQL_Connection
Error   6   error C2556: 'void *(__cdecl *sql::SQLException::operator new(void))(size_t,const std::nothrow_t &) throw()' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'void *(__cdecl *sql::SQLException::operator new(void))(size_t) throw(std::bad_alloc)'  c:\program files\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.7\include\cppconn\exception.h    98  1   MySQL_Connection
Error   7   error C2090: function returns array c:\program files\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.7\include\cppconn\exception.h    98  1   MySQL_Connection
Error   8   error C2556: 'void *(__cdecl *sql::SQLException::operator new(void))(size_t,std::allocator<_Ty> &)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'void *(__cdecl *sql::SQLException::operator new(void))(size_t) throw(std::bad_alloc)'   c:\program files\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.7\include\cppconn\exception.h    98  1   MySQL_Connection
Error   9   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/scoped_ptr.hpp': No such file or directory    C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.7\include\mysql_driver.h 30  1   MySQL_Connection
```

I checked that what is error, then it shows me that error is in `exception.h`. and that line is `MEMORY_ALLOC_OPERATORS(SQLException)`.

The code of this macro is below.

```
#define MEMORY_ALLOC_OPERATORS(Class) \
    void* operator new(size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) { return ::operator new(size); }  \
    void* operator new(size_t, void*) throw(); \
    void* operator new(size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) throw(); \
    void* operator new[](size_t) throw (std::bad_alloc); \
    void* operator new[](size_t, void*) throw(); \
    void* operator new[](size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) throw(); \
    void* operator new(size_t N, std::allocator<Class>&);
```

Maybe it is violating rule of overloading.
What should i do to resolve this? And i want to write code in `c++` only, not in `c#`.

Entire File :

```
// MySQL_Connection.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

#define DB_HOST_NAME "localhost"
#define DB_USERNAME "root"
#define DB_PASSWORD "Passw0rd"
#define DB_SCHEMA_NAME "TESTDB"

//#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

// The one and only application object

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;



int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    Driver *driver;
    Connection *con;
    ResultSet *rs;
    Statement *stmt;
    PreparedStatement  *pre_stmt;

    int id;
    char* name;
    char flag;
    cout << "Connecting to MySQL database...";

    /* Create a connection */
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect(DB_HOST_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

    try
    {
        if ( con->isValid() ) /* This method is used to check that mysql connection is alive or not */
        {
        /* Connect to mysql database */
            con->setSchema(DB_SCHEMA_NAME);


            /* Creating statement for inserting data into test table */
            stmt = con->createStatement();
            stmt->execute("USE " DB_SCHEMA_NAME );
            stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test");
            stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE test ( id INT, name VARCHAR(30) )");

            cout << "\nTable is created.";
            cout << "\n\n Below Operations are done by \"Statement.\"";

            stmt->execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 1, 'Unnat' ) ");
            stmt->execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 2, 'Kunal' ) ");
            stmt->execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 3, 'Abhishek' ) ");
            stmt->execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 4, 'Mithun' ) ");
            stmt->execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 5, 'Kiran' ) ");

            cout << "\nData Inserted.";

            delete stmt;

            /* Creating statement for fetching data from test table*/
            stmt = con->createStatement();
            rs = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id ASC");

            cout << "ID\tNAME\n";
            cout << "--\t----\n";

            while ( rs->next() ) // next() will check weather next data is present or not
            {
                /*
                    * rs->getInt(x) : get the numbered column data, specified in parameter
                        [ NOTE ] : column number starts form 1, not 0.
                    * rs->getString ( "column-name" ) :  fetch data of given column in parameter
                */
                cout << rs->getInt(1) << rs->getString("name");
            }

            delete rs;
            delete stmt;

            /* Insert operation using PreparedStatement. */
            cout << "\nInsert operation using PreparedStatement.\n\n";

            do 
            {
                pre_stmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test VALUES ( ?, ? ) ");

                cout << "ID : ";
                cin >> id;

                cout << "Name : ";
                cin >> name;

                pre_stmt->setInt ( 1, id );
                pre_stmt->setString( 2, name );

                cout << "Data Added.\n";

                cout << "\nDo you want to continue? [Y/N] :";
                cin >> flag;
            } while (flag == 'Y' || flag == 'y');

            delete pre_stmt;
        }
    }
    catch (exception e)
    {
        cout << "Error :";
        //cout << "Error on " << __LINE__ << " \n\t in ( " << __FUNCTION__ << " ) ";
        e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first error means that the compiler does not know what `string` means. I assume it refers to `std::string`. You should look not only at line 98, but also at lines above it. However, this is not normal; It should build.

Comment: Maybe order of include files - can you show the actual C++ file rather than the list of errors.

Comment: @PaulF i edited my question and the entire file is here.

Comment: did you forget any header file like `#include <mysql_connection.h>` ?

Comment: try adding _#include <string>_ after _#include <stdio.h>_

Comment: @ubuntugod i did include, but then i comment it. because it gave me error "mysql_connection.h" is not file or directory.

Comment: @PaulF tried. now the error has gone and another error pops up. libmysql.lib is missing. if anyone have this .lib file? then please share with me, it will be very grateful.

Comment: @divine_child Also check that the dlls like libmysql.dll are 32 bit if your machine is 32 bit or 64 bit if its 64 bit and link them properly.

Comment: @ubuntugod my machine is 64 bit and i have 32 bit's. so googling about 64 bit dll.

Comment: @divine_child try searching for the missing dlls [here](http://dllfiles.com)

Comment: @ubuntugod Thank you !! :)